# Passing a function reference with any arguments to another function in Scala

Tags: scala, function-pointers

What is the best way to pass a function reference in Scala to another function in cases you don't know the function arguments (e.g. you would like to use reflection on it etc)?

I'm trying to define something like this:

```
def test(f: (Any*) => Any) = ... // Any implementation
```

and call it with like:

```
def somefunc( arg1 : String, arg2 : Int, ... ) = {} // Any function with any arguments
test(somefunc) // Pass the reference to the function
```

Is it possible to do at all?

Comment: Yeah, should be possible with `.tupled` on functions and hlists to abstract over the tuple arity.

Comment: Yeah, should be possible with `.tupled` on functions and hlists to abstract over the tuple arity.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you want to do with the function later on. A simple solution would be to use generics:

```
def somefunc( arg1 : String ) = {} // Any function with any arguments
def test[X,Y]( f : X => Y) = f

def main(args: Array[String]) {
    test( somefunc )
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately this will work only for functions with one argument. If you check this with `def somefunc2( arg1 : String, arg2 : Int ) = {}` - it won't compile :(

Comment: @abdmob I don't think there is a way to declare a function type with an arbitrary number of arguments. Scala doesn't have variadic generics. That is why you have many tuple classes (up to 20?) and Function types.

Comment: yes, it is what I'm afraid so. And looking for any workaround except writing a lot of dummy functions :/

Comment: In scala library `Function1 extends AnyRef`, so you can use `AnyRef`. But you might prefer writing dummy functions - as this does not restrict function type at all. Another way is to write implicit casts from each function to some custom class and use it. But this still requires you to write lots of implicit casts - but may be reasonable if you have lots of methods like `test`

Comment: @Archeg I tried AnyRef but it won't work too (you will get a compiler error because Scala think you're trying to pass the function result as AnyRef).

Comment: @abdmob No, I meant that you can skip type check at all: `def b(x: AnyRef) { println(x) }` Then `b((x: Int) => 5)` works and prints `<function1>` as supposed to

Comment: Well, I think it possible to use `def test( f : AnyRef) = {}` and call it like `test(somefunc _)` anyway, maybe I'll try to do something with it. Thanks!

Comment: @abdmob You might want to try to look at scala macros. But they are very complicated and I am no helper here.

Answer (score 0):

To expand on @Jens' answer, with the same idea you can add more than 1 parameter:

```
scala> def somefunc( arg1 : String, arg2: String ) = {println(arg1 + arg2)}
def test[X,Y,Z]( f : (X,Y) => Z) = f
test( somefunc )("foo", "bar")
```

output:

```
somefunc: (arg1: String, arg2: String)Unit

scala> test: [X, Y, Z](f: (X, Y) => Z)(X, Y) => Z

scala> foobar
```